# formula column has to be calculated and shown the result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Table input

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#t1') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #t1 
CREATE TABLE #t1
    ([a] int, [b] int, [c] varchar(100))
;

INSERT INTO #t1
    ([a], [b], [c])
VALUES
    (1, 2, 'a+b'),
    (5, 6, 'a*b'),
    (2, 1, 'a-b'),
    (3, 8, 'b/a')
;

select * from #t1
```

Result of the table

[image]

expected output

[image]

The expected result was shown above.
In a table we have some columns and formula for each record, we need to show all columns, but in the formula column instead of formula we need to show the calculated result based on the formula column (here c)

***Note***: we need this to be dynamic we don't know what will be the formula we need to use the formula column.formula cannot be static

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: you've shown some sample formulae, is that all you have to deal with? Also, have you made any attempt at a solution at all or are you just expecting an answer to solve your problem?

Comment: @Tanner, This was expecting a suggestion on how to derive it. the formulas  will be dynamic

Comment: @brahmareddy perhaps explain that in the post and provide some more complex examples too otherwise you will get answer like the one below.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple approach that uses dynamic sql to execute the formula:

```
CREATE TABLE #t1
(
    [a] INT,
    [b] INT,
    [c] VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO #t1
(
    [a],
    [b],
    [c]
)
VALUES
(5, 2, 'a*b');

DECLARE @cFormula AS NVARCHAR(20);

SELECT TOP 1
    @cFormula = c
FROM #t1;

DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(50) = 
        N'SELECT TOP 1 a, b, ' + @cFormula + ' AS cResult FROM #t1 AS t';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;

DROP TABLE #t1;
```

Produces:

```
a   b   cResult
5   2   10
```

This will work for a single row, so you could use this method with some loop mechanism to iterate over the rows, possibly a cursor. You've not provided any additional columns to show if you have an ID or something that you can use for ordering, so this answer is provided with that in mind.

Comment: thanks for the solution, is there any solution without using loops since my table will have a minimum of 1 lack records and columns will be more

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN TRAN
DECLARE @Strt INT ,@End INT 


IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#t1') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #t1 
CREATE TABLE #t1
    ([a] int, [b] int, [c] varchar(100),[D] numeric(22,6))
;

INSERT INTO #t1
    ([a], [b], [c])
VALUES
    (1, 2, 'a+b'),
    (5, 6, 'a*b'),
    (2, 1, 'a-b'),
    (3, 8, 'b/a')

IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#TT') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #TT
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()Over(Order by a)Rowno,* INTO #TT FROM #t1

SET @Strt =1
SELECT @End=MAX(Rowno)FROM #TT

    WHILE @Strt <=@END BEGIN

        DECLARE @Formula AS NVARCHAR(20),@sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

        SELECT @Formula = c 
        FROM  #TT WHERE Rowno = @Strt

        SET @sql=' 
                UPDATE #TT SET D ='+@Formula+'
                WHERE Rowno ='''+Convert(Nvarchar,@Strt)+''''
        PRINT @sql
        EXECUTE(@sql)

        SET @Strt= @Strt+1
    END

    SELECT * FROM #TT

ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply use `CASE` since there is not many options

```
SELECT a, b, CASE
     WHEN c = 'a+b' or c = 'b+a' THEN a + b
     WHEN c = 'a-b' THEN a - b
     WHEN c = 'a*b' or c = 'b*a' THEN a * b
     WHEN c = 'a/b' THEN a / b
     WHEN c = 'b-a' THEN b - a
     WHEN c = 'b/a' THEN b / a
END c
FROM #t1
```

You may use `CURSOR` to have a more versatile solution

```
DECLARE c CURSOR FOR SELECT a, b, c FROM #t1;
DECLARE @v varchar(100)
DECLARE @a int
DECLARE @b int
DECLARE @sqlcmd varchar(8000)

OPEN c
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @a, @b, @v
SET @sqlcmd = 'SELECT ' + @v + ' FROM (SELECT CAST(' + CAST(@a as varchar) + ' AS DECIMAL(10,2)) as a, CAST(' + CAST(@b as varchar) + ' AS DECIMAL(10,2)) as b) t'
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @a, @b, @v
    IF (@@FETCH_STATUS <> 0) BREAK;
    SET @sqlcmd = @sqlcmd + (' UNION ALL SELECT ' + @v + ' FROM (SELECT CAST(' + CAST(@a as varchar) + ' AS DECIMAL(10,2)) as a, CAST(' + CAST(@b as varchar) + ' AS DECIMAL(10,2)) as b) t')
END   

PRINT @sqlcmd
EXEC (@sqlcmd)
CLOSE c   
DEALLOCATE c
```

[demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=400a63ef353970aea9bc027037d15c69)

Comment: I suppose OP wants support for arbitrary formulas.

Comment: @jarhl I suppose he does not

Comment: @RadimBača, thanks for the quick reply. but we need this to be dynamic we don't know what will be the formula we need to use the formula column.formula cannot be static

Comment: @brahmareddy good, then you should specify the formula format better. Are just these four operations expected?

Comment: I will keep the answer so people can downvote and not post the same bad solution even though it returns the expected result ;)